# Is it safe to have Spark's local tmp folders in a shared directory

Tags: apache-spark

On our cluster, the local disks are small, while we have a huge network mounted shared file system. Is it safe to use the shared drive for this purpose? Do the tmp folders created by Spark have unique IDs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if Spark in contrast with Hadoop does not require large disk space I believe is crucial to provide a sufficiently large and potentially fast file-system (SSD).

Some important operations that Spark uses FS for includes:

- Mapping output files
- Shuffling
- RDD population
- Logging

The first three certainly require high I/O throughput therefore I would avoid to add the extra overhead of network latency otherwise I believe the Spark will become slower. The only exception is of course the case which you know that your network can reach the I/O throughput of the FS!

This is emphasized on the official Spark [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#application-properties) as well regarding the `spark.local.dir` property:

> Directory to use for "scratch" space in Spark, including map output
>   files and RDDs that get stored on disk. This should be on a fast,
>   local disk in your system. It can also be a comma-separated list of
>   multiple directories on different disks. NOTE: In Spark 1.0 and later
>   this will be overridden by SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS (Standalone),
>   MESOS_SANDBOX (Mesos) or LOCAL_DIRS (YARN) environment variables set
>   by the cluster manager.

To answer your initial answer yes the files created by Spark have unique IDs although by placing them in the same directory you will increase the possibility of ID collisions as well.

Finally, I believe that the optimal in your case would be move the logs into some shared directory and keep `spark.local.dir` under the FS.

Some useful links:

[Creating the Apache Spark working directories](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS3H8V_1.1.0/com.ibm.izoda.v1r1.azka100/topics/azkic_t_createworkdirs.htm)

[Why is Spark filling the /tmp folder?](https://community.hortonworks.com/content/supportkb/186401/why-is-spark-filling-the-tmp-folder.html)

Comment: Yes, it indeed makes it way slower, so I am sticking to local disk.